# Undo management for Realm db

Tags: realm

I am migrating my db from CoreData to Realm.

I am using NSUndoManager for CoreData.

What should be the strategy to have an undo mechanism for Realm?

Comment: This is a good, but vague question. What do you want to undo? If you can provide a specific use case we may be able to make some suggestions - as you know NSUndoManager is not the be-all end-all for handling all 'undo' situations.

Comment: User opens a form, each time he did enter a field save operation occured. Then if he touch cancel we undo all these changes.

Comment: Well, threre's your problem. Don't save the form until the user presses OK, which is typically how it's done - that gives the user a chance to review the fields to ensure they are correct before committing.

Comment: @Jay this is the simple thing I don't want. Imagine user filling form for last 2 hours then app crashes...

Comment: Obviously your app should not be crashing. If there's a threat of that, divide the data entry into manageable sections. If you want another behavior, you can implement the UndoManger in a wide variety of ways - from individual text fields to state management. In this case, it's a bit unclear what specifically you want to undo. If a customer is spending two hours filling out a form, when they undo, what do you expect to happen? Undo the field they are filling out? Restore the entire form to a state? Are you using the undo manager with NSManagedObjectContext or something else?